# SASS error when using % in property value together with 'while' loop variable

Tags: loops, sass

I'm trying to make a loop in SASS that generates scaffolding classes much like Foundation.

I tried this:

```
$colCount: 12;

$i: $colCount;
@while $i > 0 {
    $result : ($i *100) /$colCount;
  .container-#{$i}_#{$colCount} { width: $result%  ; }
  $i: $i - 1;
}
```

and expected somethig like this

```
.container-12_12 {
  width: 100%;
}

.container-11_12 {
  width: 91.6667%;
}
```

but this failed. When removing the '%' it worked out fine, except for the fact that the css is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
.container-#{$i}_#{$colCount} { width: #{$result*1%}  ; }
```

multiply the variable by 1%.

I found the solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787609/sass-error-when-using-in-property-value-together-with-for-loop-variable?rq=1).